# Android: Get Raw Byte[] Data from User's Native Camera App

Tags: android, android-camera, arrays

I am writing a custom camera application because I need to do real-time streaming and I need to access the byte array raw video data from a camera.

To simplify my work, I was wondering if I could get this raw data from the user's native camera application. I am guessing not because you must invoke it through an intent, and then you get a result. But, I need the real-time raw data, not a delayed result.

The reason for this request is that I just need to get the raw data and don't actually desire to do anything fancier than what the native camera can do.

If this is possible I'd be very grateful for any assistance!

Comment: Consider [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) for realtime video streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [`setPreviewCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback))? It will continuously give you still images of the camera preview. The only caveat is that the frame rate will probably be very low, but I don't know your use case so it might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I could get this raw data from the user's native camera application

Not in general. There are thousands of "native camera applications" for Android. None are required to publish any sort of real-time raw data feed, to the extent that is even possible given the additional layer of IPC overhead. It's entirely possible that *somebody* happens to have written a camera app that does this, and you're welcome to hunt around for it, but that may take a fair bit of time.

Comment: Ye, I suppose it's not the real-time stuff that's troubling me, but the camera interface itself. See, I'd rather focus on the streaming side instead of trying to keep users from hating the app because it is sub par to their preferred camera app.